# How to shuffle id in my MySQL table permanently in place?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with following structure and a lot of rows:

```
 id     | name    | title   |
------------------------------
```

Need to replace `id` with other value, in other words I need to permanently **shuffle** my table. What query do I need to run? This query I need to run exactly one time... no matter how long time or memory it will take.

Comment: cant you add a random numbers to existing `id`? or do you want to permute them?

Comment: shuffle to row *physically* or just need to change the ``id`` column?

Comment: I need to shuffle rows *physically*, and a whole set id may be same as before but it doesnt have to. My current range of `id` is from 1 - 800?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your rows size is 800, you may do something like bellow:

- Create a Temporary Table with all record of your table.

  e.g. `CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE (SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE)`.
- `DROP TABLE YOUR_TABLE;` .
- `CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (SELECT * FROM TMP_TABLE ORDER BY RAND() )`
- `DROP TABLE TMP_TABLE;` .

Comment: My column id, indeed is `auto-increment`. Does it change anything?:)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, it shouldn't.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk ,  I think no.

Answer (score 2):

The following query should do that following:

> - The whole id set will be same as before, just shuffle the ids;
> - `tbl` is the one to update
> - `tbl2` generates a random row_num for `tbl`
> - `tbl3` generates a random (different to above) row_num for `tbl3`
> - with `tbl2.row_num1 = tbl3.row_num2`, the shuffle is done

```
UPDATE tbl INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, (@rm1 := @rm1 + 1) as row_num1 FROM tbl CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) param ORDER BY RAND()) tbl2 
        ON tbl.id = tbl2.id
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *, (@rm2 := @rm2 + 1) as row_num2 FROM tbl CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) param ORDER BY RAND()) tbl3
        ON tbl2.row_num1 = tbl3.row_num2
SET tbl.id = tbl3.id;
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does?:)

Comment: @DylanSu he means `it` :)

Comment: @shmosel exactly:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use database `VIEW` for your purpose using shuffle logic

Otherwise use another table to backup current table and then `SELECT`  shuffle rows from the backup table. Then `TRUNCATE` the your table and then insert shuffle rows from select query of backup table.